# How to fetch data from a node.js webservice and display in iOS application?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a REST API webservice built in node.js that I access through a url. I need to get that data into an iOS application. Currently the code that I use in my HomeModel.swift gives me data in the form of bytes, instead of the expected:

```
{
  "recordsets":[[{"USERCODE":"A", "PASSWORD":"SaYX^]Kc", "FIRSTNAME":"ADMINISTRATOR", "LASTNAME":" ", "USERCLASS":"1", "CONTACTNO":"2213"}]],
  "recordset":[{"USERCODE":"A", "PASSWORD":"SaYX^]Kc", "FIRSTNAME":"ADMINISTRATOR", "LASTNAME":" ", "USERCLASS":"1", "CONTACTNO":"2213"}],
  "output":{},
  "rowsAffected":[1]
}
```

Moreover when I try to parse the data, I get the error:

> Could not cast value of type '__NSSingleObjectArrayI' (0x7fff87a90f58) to 'NSString' (0x7fff87b502e8).
> 2020-08-18 20:15:02.512836+0300 [11444:1203386] Could not cast value of type '__NSSingleObjectArrayI' (0x7fff87a90f58) to 'NSString' (0x7fff87b502e8).

The code in my HomeModel.swift file is as follows:

```
import UIKit

protocol HomeModelDelegate {
    
    func usersDownloaded(users:[User])
    
}

class HomeModel: NSObject {
    
    var delegate: HomeModelDelegate?
    let serviceUrl = "http://url.com/api/users"
    
    func getUsers() {
        
        //Download JSON data
        let url = URL(string: serviceUrl)
        
        if let url = url {
            //Create a url session
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            
            let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
                
                if error == nil {
                    //Data successfully loaded and call the parseJson function on the data
                    self.parseJson(data: data!)
                    print(data!)
                }
                else {
                    //Some error occurred
                    print("Some error occurred")
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
        //Notify the viewcontroller and pass the data back
    }
    
    func parseJson(data: Data) {
        var usrArray = [User]()
        
        //Parse the data into User struct
        do {
            //Parse the data into JSON Object
            let jsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [String:String]
            
            //Loop through each result in the JSON array
            for jsonResult in jsonArray {
                
                //Caste JSON result as a dictionary
                let jsonDict = jsonResult as! [String : String]
                
                //Create new User and set its properties
                let usr = User(usrID: jsonDict["USERNAME"]!, firstName: jsonDict["FIRSTNAME"]!, lastName: jsonDict["LASTNAME"]!, password: jsonDict["PASSWORD"]!, usrClass: jsonDict["USERCLASS"]!)
                 
                //Add the user to the array
                usrArray.append(usr)
            }
            
            //Pass the data array back to the delegate
            delegate?.usersDownloaded(users: usrArray)
            
        }
        catch{
            //Some error occurred
            print("Some error occurred")
        }
    }
}
```

How do I solve this problem and display the "recordset" data onto my console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error you got is because of this line in `parseJson(data:)` method:

```
let jsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [String:String]
```

**Why is that?**

You're trying to force cast your JSON object into dictionary of key and value type String. Keys may be of type String but values for sure aren't and this is exactly what error is trying to tell you. Your are trying to cast something that's Array into String which never will happen.

If you look at first key-value pair in JSON pasted above you can see that key `recordsets` is of type String but for value this isn't true. Value is of type Array and casting this into dictionary of key and value type String will fail.

**How do you solve this problem and display recordset value in your console?**

I would solve this problem with a help of Decodable protocol.

First I would declare my `DataTransferObject` and make it conform to Decodable protocol. In there you can see that properties have exact same name as your keys in JSON. If you would misspell any of this properties decoding JSON will fail so be careful.

```
struct DataTransferObject: Decodable {
    let recordsets: [[User]]
    let recordset: [User]
    let output: OutputObject
    let rowsAffected: [Int]
}
```

Then you must declare types that are missing in your `DataTransferObject` all conforming to decodable too. Because properties in `User` object are named differently than keys in JSON you have to use `CodingKeys` enumerator to associate them with JSON keys.

```
struct User: Decodable {
    let usrID: String
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
    let password: String
    let usrClass: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case usrID = "USERCODE"
        case password = "PASSWORD"
        case firstName = "FIRSTNAME"
        case lastName = "LASTNAME"
        case usrClass = "USERCLASS"
    }
}

struct OutputObject: Decodable {
    
}
```

Then you can rework your `parseJson(data:)` method to use `JSONDecoder` object for decoding your JSON and print `recordset` property to console.

```
func parseJson(data: Data) {
    do {
        // Instantiate JSONDecoder object
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        
        // Decode JSON to DataTransferObject
        let dto = try decoder.decode(DataTransferObject.self, from: data)
        
        // Print out recordset property
        print("*** Decoded recordset property: \(dto.recordset)")
        
    } catch {
        //Some error occurred
        print("Some error occurred: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do I declare the DataTransferObject? Should I create a new swift file for it?

Comment: This is totally up to you. If you want clear file structure then I would say yes. Please make sure to accept this answer if it answers your question.

Comment: You must change just related objects if your JSON scheme changes. `parseJson(data:)` method will always work if your objects have exactly the same scheme as your JSON.